# Jogo não reconhece Input de teclado pelo "pynput"

Tags: python, teclado, automatização, pynput

Estou criando um bot para pressionar a tecla: "A" dentro de um jogo.

Código que estou utilizando:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller;
from time import sleep;

keyboard = Controller();

sleep(2)

keyboard.press("a");
keyboard.release("a");
```

No bloco de notas o script funciona bem, pressiona a tecla sem problemas.

Porém, dentro do jogo não funciona. Ele não simula a tecla desejada.

Dei uma pesquisada e aparentemente tem a ver com o foco do sistema. Como resolvo?

Comment: Script/Bot não fere as regras do jogo?

Answer (score 1):

Isso são mecanismos de segurança dos jogos, a maioria consegue diferenciar inputs reais de inputs de scripts.

O vídeo a seguir tem uma explicação do por quê input pelo "pyautogui" não funcionaou no jogo dele, mas o mesmo conceito se aplica ao "keyboard". O vídeo está em inglês ([Vídeo "PyAutoGUI not working? Use DirectInput"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFDGgFRqVIs))

No caso ele sugeriu a utilização do [PyDirectInput](https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput) para fazer os inputs de mouse e teclado de uma maneira que os games interpretem como um input nativo. Mas mesmo assim, esteja ciente que as desenvolvedoras de jogos estão sempre buscando formas de não reconhecer entradas de script, e cuidado para não ferir as regras do jogo em sí.